# Mongoose. number of entries for specific property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have collection People.
Every person in this collection has favorite color. here example of person

```
{
id:123,
color:'red',
...
...
}
```

What is an elegant way to go through collection People, and
query all possible colors form that collection and how many people love that color?
Example of output:
'green':125,
'yellow': 76
etc...
Many thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
     {$group: {_id:"$color",
               numLiking:{$sum:1}
     } }
] );
```

You'll get back something like:

```
[ { _id:"red", numLiking:7 }, { _id:"green", numLiking:17 }, ... ]
```